# Align items center doesn't work properly on table row?

Tags: html, css

I want to align table.

### My code

```css
tr {
        height: 70px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

    tr:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Swanson</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cleveland</td>
        <td>Brown</td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Just check my `align-items: center;`

When set it to align vertical alignment I got a problem.
On hover on row all row moves by 2 pixels (this border). Without `align-items: center` , to work good but is not aligned.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

Add a transparent border on normal state and add a px border on hover. This wlll help you.

Your row is flickering not because of the `align-items`. Its because that there was no border initially and on hover you added a 2 px border. This made the lower element to move px down. To resolve this add a transparent border on normal state. This will consumes a 2px border initially and on hover, you are just updating the border color.

```css
tr {
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

tr:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Swanson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cleveland</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is brilliant

Comment: I am find another solution. I set height: calc(70px - 2px) ;

Comment: @yanadod that may solve the problem. But using `calc` in css will create performance issues.